# How do I access What's App Manager from Business Manager after adding What's App Business Account?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I want to start using What's App Business API for my business.

I have successfully registered/verified my business on FB Business Manager and added a What's App Account account there (see screenshot below). The next step is to [add a phone number and display name](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/456220311516626?id=2129163877102343), get the registration certificate for the number, and [register the number with my WA Business API client](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/account) (AFAIK).

However, I don't see anywhere in FB Business Manager to add phone number and download registration certificate. There is no "What's App Manager" visible in my Business Manager account settings (see screenshot below). I've checked everywhere. Please help!

[image: WA Business Account added]

[image]